# Wordpress previous / next returning static permalink

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

This is the twentyseventeen theme. This is in header.php and it is being called directly underneath the featured image call.

Using the below code, only the next link is showing and it is giving a static permalink of my oldest post by date, on every single post. The featured image here works fine.

```
<?php
// If a regular post or page, and not the front page, show the featured image.
if ( has_post_thumbnail() && ( is_single() || ( is_page() && ! twentyseventeen_is_frontpage() ) ) ) :
    echo '<div class="single-featured-image-header">';
    the_post_thumbnail( 'twentyseventeen-featured-image' );
    next_post_link( '%link', 'Next post in category', TRUE );
    previous_post_link( '%link', 'previous post in category', TRUE );
    echo '</div><!-- .single-featured-image-header -->';
endif;
?>
```

HTML output:

```
    <div class="single-featured-image-header">
<img width="1920" height="1080" src="http://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/image.jpg" class="attachment-twentyseventeen-featured-image size-twentyseventeen-featured-image wp-post-image" alt="" />
<a href="http://website.com/post" rel="next">Post Title <span class="meta-nav">→</span></a>
</div><!-- .single-featured-image-header -->
```

I need assistance figuring out where this logic is being applied.

Comment: So what you want , you want to remove the permalinks or need changes

Comment: Well based on my PHP the output should be links to the previous and next post, and it only links back to itself. It also only shows the next button with the wrong title. I just want it to work like the wordpress codex describes.